# Get HTML from web page shared from browser through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, share-intent

I'm looking to get the HTML from a web page shared by the user with my app.

So I have this intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And the code in my activity:

```
String action = intent.getAction(); 
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND) && 
intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) { 
    String s = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT); 
    output.setText(s); //output: a TextView that holds the URL 
}
```

This outputs the link.. but I need the HTML. Any thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTTP client API (OkHttp, `HttpUrlConnection`, etc.) and make an HTTP `GET` request for that URL. IOW, do what a Web browser does.